# Convert string to a date in db2

Tags: sql, db2

Ok I was able to get it fixed.

I want to convert the string "10-Feb-2019 11:20" to "DD-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss".

I tried to date but it wasn't working. I saw on other threads that the translate function might be the way to go. However I am somewhat new to SQL and none of the explanation of how to use translate in this manner where in a way I could understand.

I am using windows and a pretty recent version of db2

The original is

> select
>
> case
>
> when (length(column) = 50 then
>
> to_date(substr(column, 1, 17),'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi'))
>
> else
>
> date
>
> end
>
> from table

So it is finding the date within a larger string.

the code now is

> Select
>
> case
>
> when (length(column) = 50 then
>
> to_timestamp(substr(column, 1, 17),'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi'))
>
> else
>
> date
>
> end
>
> From table

Note: I just tried to_timestamp('10-Feb-2019 11:20', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24)
and I got "10-Feb-2019 11:20" cannot be interpreted using format string "dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi" for the TIMESTAMP_FORMAT function.

Comment: Please show the `to_date()` statement you are using.  Also, explain how this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DB2, `date` does not have a time component.

So, try `to_timestamp()`:

```
select to_timestamp('10-Feb-2019 11:20', 'DD-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi')
```

Note that seconds are not in the string value, so they should not be in the format specification.  However, the final value will have seconds -- all set to zero.

Comment: Correct format string should be `DD-mon-yyyy hh24:mi`, not `DD-mm-yyyy hh24:mi`.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein . . . Good catch.  What is really ironic is that I tested it in Oracle and it works with both `mm` and `mon`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want String -> Timestamp casting, try this:
[to_timestamp](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html)('10-Feb-2019 11:20', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi')
`to_timestamp` is an alias for `timestamp_format`.

If you want just another string representation of this timestamp (like your `10-Feb-2019 11:20` -> `10-02-2019 11:20:00`), try this:
[to_char](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html)(to_timestamp('10-Feb-2019 11:20', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi'), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
`to_char` is an alias for `varchar_format`.

Comment: I tried that but got SQL Error [22007]: "10-Feb-2019 11:20" cannot be interpreted using format string "dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi" for the TIMESTAMP_FORMAT function.

Comment: You did not what I suggested. 'mon' instead of 'mm'.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't catch that.